# unable to retrieve data using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is my code for a page...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var url = "https://natiweb-natiweb.rhcloud.com/game.php";
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
              $.each(data,function(i,user){
alert("inside json");
    alert(user.appname);
               });
            }
        );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to get data from server.... alert does not gets popped up
it works fine if I write the script code inside a js file. but i need to dynamically populate a page, hence I need to write this query inside body.
I added alert inside the json function. even that is not getting popped. I think json isn't getting executed

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: [Same-origin error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This.....

```
var url = "https://natiweb-natiweb.rhcloud.com/game.php";
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
   $.each(data,function(i,user){
    alert(user.appname[i]);
           });
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,Becoz you are getting array in that array your json is present

```
alert(user[0].appname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to auto-execute your code, that's what the example says on the jquery doc.

```
<script>
(function() {
var url = "https://natiweb-natiweb.rhcloud.com/game.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data,function(i,user){
alert("inside json");
alert(user.appname);
           });
        }
    );  

})();
</script>
```